# LESSOPEN not working

Tags: bash, command-line, less

LESSOPEN not working for me, don't know why.

In ~/.bashrc currently I have:

```
export LESSOPEN='| nl  %s'
export LESS=' -R -i --use-color'
export LESSSECURE=1
```

but LESSOPEN doesn't seem to work. LESS works fine, which I can discover by -i option (ignore-case-search). LESSSECURE also works. But LESSOPEN not.

I tried `export LESSOPEN='|lesspipe.sh  %s'` or `export LESSOPEN='|pygmentize  %s` also `export LESSCOLORIZER='pygmentize'`.

I have no clue. Any idea?

Comment: try to comment out the LESSSECURE option, as it invalidates the "|" feature, apparently. See : https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html#SECURITY

Comment: Is this still an issue for you?

Comment: Thanks @OlivierDulac, I still haven't tried it but I will and hope that works.